# Custom walker nav - Add sequential number as class

Tags: menus, walker

I'm getting to grips with the walker at the moment, but i need some assistance in getting my desired effect.

My walker function looks like:

```
class ik_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu{
    //start of the sub menu wrap
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $output .= '<nav class="site-navigation" role="navigation">
                        <ul>';
    }
    //end of the sub menu wrap
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $output .= '
                    </ul>
            <button id="menu" class="menu-button" type="button" role="button" aria-label="Menu Toggle">
              <span class="icon-menu"></span>
            </button>
        </div>';
    }
    //add the description to the menu item output
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
        $class_names = $value = '';
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';
        $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';
        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )  ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'  . esc_attr( $item->xfn      ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        if(strlen($item->description)>2){ $item_output .= '<br /><span class="sub">' . $item->description . '</span>'; }
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

What I need is for each `a` within the `li` of the nav, to have it's own class that start with `c` then a number - starting at 1.

```
<a href="[link]" class="c1"></a>
<a href="[link]" class="c2"></a>
<a href="[link]" class="c3"></a>
```

I then need a `span` after each a, with a class when I can specify somewhere, if possible? I know how to get the `span` in there, but I can't figure out from my searches if you can indeed set specific individual classes as I need to do things like:

```
<span class="paw-icon"></span>
```

Any help would be VERY much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
class ik_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $GLOBALS['ik_walker_counter'] = 0;
        $output .= '<nav class="site-navigation" role="navigation">'.
            '<ul>';
    }

    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $output .= '</ul>'.
            '<button id="menu" class="menu-button" type="button" role="button" aria-label="Menu Toggle">'.
            '<span class="icon-menu"></span>'.
            '</button>'.
            '</div>';
    }

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;
        global $ik_walker_counter;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
        $class_names = $value = '';
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';
        $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';
        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )  ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'  . esc_attr( $item->xfn      ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ' class="c'.(++$ik_walker_counter).'"';
        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        if(strlen($item->description)>2){ $item_output .= '<br /><span class="sub">' . $item->description . '</span>'; }
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= '<span class="'.$args->my_individual_class.'"></span>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

}
```

Your `c1` through `cn` classes are tracked/counted by the global `$ik_walker_counter` variable, which is reset every time we start a new level. The individual class goes as new parameter in your **walker arguments** ( e.g., `'my_individual_class' => 'paw-icon'`.

Comment: Could I specify a series of class for 'my_individual_class'? I noticed when I tested this that I'm not seeing the classes being added to the anchors

Comment: Sorry for that. There was a typo in `attribuTes`. Yes, you can also specify a space-separated sequence of classes for `my_individual_class`.

Comment: Ah brilliant ,thank you. What would be the best option if i needed a different `my_individual_class` for each span. Just use jQuery or is there an efficient way to specify this in some sort of array?

Comment: Why don't you use the CSS class for each menu element in the WordPress admin? If you don't see it, just activate it in the _Screen Options_ (upper right area). Then you can use `$item->classes`.